# How to remove the translucent white theme overlay introduced in Firefox 44?

Tags: firefox, themes, user-interface

Starting from Firefox 44, the browser overlays all themes with a translucent white overlay. In Firefox 43, the theme you had chosen wasn't overlayed (except  for the active tab in the tabs row).

(Because I'm using a [black theme](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/just-black/) it turns most of the theme into gray. I added another theme as an example in case it still isn't clear what I mean.)

How can I remove the white semi-transparent layer that overlays all themes (except for the top part)?

### The old behavior

[image: Firefox 38.6 ESR (black theme)]
[image: Firefox 38.6 ESR (Freshness theme)]

### The new behavior

[image: Firefox 44.0 (black theme)]
[image: Firefox 44.0 (Freshness theme)]

Comment: I like the theme. Is it a complete theme? What is its name?

Comment: The Stylish add-on lets you implement, and in some cases modify, themes and skins.  Don't know if it will solve this specific problem, but it might be worth testing.

Comment: Can you link us to the theme? I could play around with the chrome css and probably revert it.

Comment: I can only view images hosted on `i.stack.imgur.com` but images on `i.imgur.com` are blocked, so I only see half of the images here.

Comment: @RogUE The question has been updated with more information.

Comment: @MC10 The question has been updated with more information.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to undo part of the effect using the [Classic Theme Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/) extension.

1. Install *Classic Theme Restorer* and restart Firefox.
2. Go to the add-ons manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>)
3. In the Add-ons Manager tab, select the *Extensions* panel.
4. Click the *Preferences* button for the Classic Theme Restorer add-on.
5. In the Classic Theme Restorer options, click the *Settings* button and then *Firefox preset* to undo all the tweaks to Firefox’ looks that Classic Theme Restorer makes by default.
   [image: Click "Firefox preset" in the "Settings" menu]
6. Under *Toolbars (3)*, Check "Navigation Toolbar: Remove background color". Also check the "Remove background color" checkbox directly underneath *Bookmarks Toolbar*.
7. Under *Tab colors & text*, choose a gradient that approximates the colors found in Firefox 43. [image: For example "silver" and "#333333".]

### End result

[image: The end result looks much like the old style, but it differs in the fact that the gradient does not stretch beyond the active tab.]

(Thanks to @Charles Kelley for the [suggestion](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/498582).)

*Note: some things are looking different because I was on Windows when writing the question but using Linux Mint when writing the answer.*